# Python/Pandas - DataFrame Index - Move one month forward

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

I have a DataFrame:

```
                Actual       Pred
Date                             
2005-04-01        10.2  10.364470
2005-05-01         9.4   9.542778
2005-06-01         9.5   9.684794
2005-07-01         9.4   9.547604
2005-08-01         9.7   9.768893
```

I want to add one month to each of the DataFrame's indexes, so it gets to look like this:

```
                Actual       Pred
Date                             
2005-05-01        10.2  10.364470
2005-06-01         9.4   9.542778
2005-07-01         9.5   9.684794
2005-08-01         9.4   9.547604
2005-09-01         9.7   9.768893
```

How do I do that?

---

Important comment:

When I command `print type(DataFrame.index[0])` to find out the data type of the index, I get:

```
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Just for you to know that it is a Pandas Timestamp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`pd.DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
In [82]: df
Out[82]: 
            Actual       Pred
Date                         
2005-04-01    10.2  10.364470
2005-05-01     9.4   9.542778
2005-06-01     9.5   9.684794
2005-07-01     9.4   9.547604
2005-08-01     9.7   9.768893

df.index = df.index + pd.DateOffset(months=1)

In [85]: df
Out[85]: 
            Actual       Pred
Date                         
2005-05-01    10.2  10.364470
2005-06-01     9.4   9.542778
2005-07-01     9.5   9.684794
2005-08-01     9.4   9.547604
2005-09-01     9.7   9.768893
```