# Shifting the values of a column in pandas dataframe one month forward

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Is there a way to shift the values of a column in pandas dataframe one month forward? (note that I want to thift the column value and not the date value).
For example, if I have:

```
           ColumnA   ColumnB
2016-10-01       1  0
2016-09-30       2  1
2016-09-29       5  1
2016-09-28       7  1
.
.
2016-09-01       3  1
2016-08-31       4  7
2016-08-30       4  7
2016-08-29       9  7
2016-08-28       10  7
```

Then I want to be able to shift the values in ColumnB
 one month forward, to get the desired output:

```
           ColumnA   ColumnB
2016-10-01       1  1
2016-09-30       2  7
2016-09-29       5  7
2016-09-28       7  7
.
.
2016-09-01       3  7
2016-08-31       3  X
2016-08-30       4  X
2016-08-29       9  x
2016-08-28       10  x
```

In the data I have, the value if fixed for each month (for example, the value in ColumnB was 1 during september), so the fact that the number of days is a bit different each month should not be a problem.

This seems related [Python/Pandas - DataFrame Index - Move one month forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095311/python-pandas-dataframe-index-move-one-month-forward), but in the linked question the OP wanted to shift the whole frame, and I want to shift only selected columns.

Comment: What do you want to happen if August 31 were in your dataset? Both Aug 31 and 30 would map to Sep 30.

Comment: @Ted Petrou see my comment to you in the discussion below the answer of beniev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not too elegant, but you can do something like that:

```
df=df.reset_index()
df['index']=pd.to_datetime(df['index'],infer_datetime_format=True)
df['offset']=df['index']-pd.DateOffset(months=1)
res=df.merge(df,right_on='index',left_on='offset',how='left')
```

and just take from res the columns you want

Comment: This wouldn't work if there was august 31 in the data. Both aug 30 and 31 would map to sep 30.

Comment: @Ted Petrou thanks for your comment. I updated my question, as the data that I have might be more comfortable to work with.

Comment: @Ted Petrou So one can use `pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='M')` instead of `pd.DateOffset(months=1)`

Comment: @beniev if I understand correctly, your solution adds a new column to df, where the dates are shifted by month. Could you explain how can I use it to shift the values in ColumnB by month?

Comment: @MiriamFarber what you'll have in `ColomnB_y` after the merging is exactly the shifted `B` column.

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a new index of pandas Periods for each month and then find get the value of each month and use pandas automatic index alignment to create a new column.

```
df1 = df.copy()
orig_idx = df.index
df1.index = orig_idx.to_period('M')
col_b_new = df1.groupby(level=0)['ColumnB'].first().tshift(1)
df1['ColumnB_new'] = col_b_new
df1.index = orig_idx
```

Output

```
            ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnB_new
2016-10-01        1        0          1.0
2016-09-30        2        1          7.0
2016-09-29        5        1          7.0
2016-09-28        7        1          7.0
2016-09-01        3        1          7.0
2016-08-31        4        7          NaN
2016-08-30        4        7          NaN
2016-08-29        9        7          NaN
2016-08-28       10        7          NaN
```